# Contract out of gas on deployment

Tags: ink

I am new to ink and trying to run a smartcontract that gets built and deployed correctly but on executing the `deposit()` method from the contract, it terminates with `Contract.Out.Of.Gas`after doing some computation in `insert()` method given below.

In debug logs, I cannot find any reason why the contract limit gets exhausted. I did try to set the gas limit to the max value it can accept but it just did a few more computations and exhausted the gas limit.

I am not sure where should I start to look for the root cause of the problem.

This is Mixer contract which has 2 ContractRef `PoseidonRef` and `MixerVerifierRef`, following are the structure details about smartcontract for reference:

```
#[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(SpreadAllocate)]
    pub struct Mixer {
        deposit_size: Balance,
        merkle_tree: merkle_tree::MerkleTree,
        used_nullifiers: Mapping<[u8; 32], bool>,
        poseidon: PoseidonRef,
        verifier: MixerVerifierRef,
    }

#[ink(message, payable)]
pub fn deposit(&mut self, commitment: [u8; 32]) -> Result<u32> {
    assert!(
        self.env().transferred_value() == self.deposit_size,
        "Deposit size is not correct"
    );

    self.merkle_tree.insert(self.poseidon.clone(), commitment)
}

// merkle_tree.insert
pub fn insert(&mut self, hasher: PoseidonRef, leaf: [u8; 32]) -> Result<u32> {
    ...
    for i in 0..self.levels {
        if current_index % 2 == 0 {
            left = current_level_hash;
            right = zeroes::zeroes(i);
            self.filled_subtrees.insert(i, &current_level_hash);
        } else {
            left = self.filled_subtrees.get(&i).unwrap_or_default();
            right = current_level_hash;
        }

        current_level_hash = self.hash_left_right(hasher.clone(), left, right)?;
        current_index = current_index / 2;
     }
   ....
}

// hash_left_right
fn hash_left_right(
        &self,
        hasher: PoseidonRef,
        left: [u8; 32],
        right: [u8; 32],
    ) -> Result<[u8; 32]> {
        let inputs = vec![left, right];
        hasher.hash(inputs).map_err(|_| mixer::Error::HashError)
}
```

Any advice or help is much appreciated. Thank you!

I am using ink! v3.0.0-rc9 and redspot for testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you end up figuring it out?

An approach to debugging this could be with a local instance of the [`substrate-contracts-node`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node#download-binary).

This node comes with the typical Alice, Bob, etc. accounts that are endowed with a huge amount of tokens. In the [Contracts UI](https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/) or polkadot-js you can then submit the transaction from e.g. Alice and the UI displays the amount of gas used.

So this should give you an idea if the gas costs are in general in a reasonable domain. If this already fails it's likely that you're logic is unbound in some way.

In order to debug this you could then create a Rust unit test ([like here](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/examples/flipper/lib.rs#L38-L47)) and see if that finishes.

Comment: yeah we, started using the local instance of the substrate-contract-node.